# What you call this web site menu element?

Tags: design, web, google, tab

The Google material design is new, I like to know how you call this menu element, or how will you name it:
[image]

The page link:https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods

**The item we are talking about is located in the sub head area.

In this link it works like menu, and has a class name "nav-tab-list". In some other material design site it works like just a tab(will not target to different page).

Comment: Does it need a new name? If it is a link to a new page, I would refer to it as a menu item; if it is not, then I would refer to it as a tab.

Answer (score 3):

It is a tab, styled according to the [Material Design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#) as you hinted.

According to the [Navigation Pattern](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation.html#navigation-patterns) from Google:

> Tabs allow users to quickly move between a small number of equally important views.
>
> Appropriate for these hierarchies:
>
> - Parents with embedded child views
> - A group of sibling views
>
> Recommended for:
>
> - Frequent switching between views
> - Apps with few top-level views
> - Promoting awareness of alternate views

In this case, I would say that it corresponds to *Apps with few top-level views*. While MDL was created mainly for applications, most concepts can be applied to a regular Web site. You may have to adapt things here and there.

Answer (score 1):

As the name 'nav-tab-list' or Navigation tab list also suggests, these are basically navigation elements in tabs or call it Tab elements or simply Menu items.

Also, there are basically two elements in a tab, Indicator(White bold line in your case) and Label. Nothing more to it, I think.